# POST an array from an HTML form without javascript

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form that is a little complex and I am hoping to simplify the server-side (PHP) processing by natively POSTing an array of tuples.

The first part of the form represents a *User*:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Address
- etc

The second part of the form represents a *Tree*:

- Fruit
- Height
- etc

The problem is that I need to be able to POST multiple *Trees* for a single *User* in the same form. I would like to send the information as a single *User* with an array of *Trees* but this might be too complex to do with a form. The only thing that comes to mind is using javascript to create some JSON message with a User object and an array of Tree objects. But it would be nice to avoid javascript to support more users (some people have scripts turned off).

Comment: Does the array guarantee order? I would like an array of Tree objects which would have multiple fields, so this would mean I have to use multiple arrays to represent a Tree and the arrays must be ordered so I can figure out which Tree they represent.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

[check this one out.](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="address">

<input type="text" name="tree[tree1][fruit]">
<input type="text" name="tree[tree1][height]">

<input type="text" name="tree[tree2][fruit]">
<input type="text" name="tree[tree2][height]">

<input type="text" name="tree[tree3][fruit]">
<input type="text" name="tree[tree3][height]">
```

it should end up like this in the $_POST[] array (PHP format for easy visualization)

```
$_POST[] = array(
    'firstname'=>'value',
    'lastname'=>'value',
    'email'=>'value',
    'address'=>'value',
    'tree' => array(
        'tree1'=>array(
            'fruit'=>'value',
            'height'=>'value'
        ),
        'tree2'=>array(
            'fruit'=>'value',
            'height'=>'value'
        ),
        'tree3'=>array(
            'fruit'=>'value',
            'height'=>'value'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What chars are allowed in array indexing? Can we use ,.:` @? Example: `tree[tree 1][fr ui_t]` `tree[tree.1][fru:it]` `tree[tree@1][fru,it]`  Is _ only safe delimiter in key naming?

Comment: would `tree[][fruit]` and `tree[][height]` not be valid to automatically index the array?

Comment: How do i get this submitted data as array/object in js to use in submit callback... i have tried `new formData($("form")[0])` and jQuery `$("form").serializeArray()` both returning `name="tree[tree1][fruit]"` as string....help

Comment: Note: it doesn't work with jquery functions to collect form data as `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`

Comment: I tried but did not work for me in laravel

Answer (score 110):

You can also post multiple inputs with the same name and have them save into an array by adding empty square brackets to the input name like this:

```
<input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment1"/>
<input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment2"/>
<input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment3"/>
<input type="text" name="comment[]" value="comment4"/>
```

If you use php:

```
print_r($_POST['comment'])
```

you will get this:

```
Array ( [0] => 'comment1' [1] => 'comment2' [2] => 'comment3' [3] => 'comment4' )
```

Comment: I feel like this is the actual answer to the posted question.