# Collect $_POSTs from multiple checkbox rows

Tags: php, arrays, foreach-loop-container

I have a form with multiple rows of checkboxes, each with a specific id, that are being displayed using a `foreach` loop.

How do you grab the `$_POST` info from something like that? I think it is like this somehow `$_POST[][]`, like a sub-array, but I cant figure out how to set it up:

```
foreach($stakholderArray as $currentEntry) {
    print "<tr class='$bgcolor'>";
    print "<td class='left'>$currentEntry[org]</td>";

    if($currentEntry['dataFound']) {  
        //if data was found for current stakeholder, display it
        print ($currentEntry['Partner']) ? '<td><input type ="checkbox" checked ="checked" /></td>' : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
        print ($currentEntry['Agreement']) ? '<td><input type ="checkbox" checked ="checked" /></td>' : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
        print ($currentEntry['Train']) ? '<td><input type ="checkbox" checked ="checked" /></td>'  : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
        print ($currentEntry['Meet'])  ? '<td><input type ="checkbox" checked ="checked" /></td>' : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
    }
    else {  //else...no stakeholder data, display empty columns
        print "<td><input type ='checkbox'/></td><td><input type ='checkbox'/></td><td><input type ='checkbox'/></td><td><input type ='checkbox'/></td><td><input type ='checkbox'/></td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }## Heading ##
```

Comment: Can the input name be a variable array? Like <input type name = "$stakeholder[][]"/>   I still cant get it to work..here is a screenshot if it help https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/102528100285286815171/albums/5708634782606194689/5708634785261526130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's somewhat related to a question i answered before: [POST an array from an HTML form without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/is-it-possible-to-post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript/9073794#9073794)

- encase them in a form
- give them an "array" name
- they end up as an array during post when submitted

related items should have like this: `name="item[collection name][collection name][]"` - note the first indices pertaining the set (for easy location), and the empty index meaning in that set, there's an array (instead of single value). so for your check boxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set1][]" value="apple" />   //imagine checked
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set1][]" value="orange" />  //imagine checked
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set1][]" value="grape" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set2][]" value="airplane" />   //imagine checked
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set2][]" value="train" />  //imagine checked
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[set2][]" value="boat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answers[solo]" value="boar" /> //single type value. note that there is no [] in the end
```

end up like this in the request array (like say POST):

```
$_POST[] = array(
    'answers' => array(
        'set1' => array('apple','orange'),   //unchecked items won't be included
        'set2' => array('airplane','train'), //unchecked items won't be included
        'solo' => 'boar'
    )
);
```

---

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($stakeholderArray as $stakeholder): ?>
    <tr>

    <?php 

        //declare so these exist regardless of data
        $partner   = '';
        $agreement = '';
        $train     = '';
        $meet      = '';

        //if we have data, mark the boxes accordingly
        if($stakeholder['dataFound']){

            $checked = 'checked ="checked"';

            //mark as checked or blank
            $partner   = ($stakeholder['Partner'])   ? $checked: '';
            $agreement = ($stakeholder['Agreement']) ? $checked: '';
            $train     = ($stakeholder['Train'])     ? $checked: '';
            $meet      = ($stakeholder['Meet'])      ? $checked: '';

        }
    ?>

       <td><input value='partner' name="stake[<?= $stakeholder ?>][partner]" type ="checkbox" <?= $partner ?> /></td>
       <td><input value='agreement' name="stake[<?= $stakeholder ?>][agreement]" type ="checkbox" <?= $agreement ?> /></td>
       <td><input value='train' name="stake[<?= $stakeholder ?>][train]" type ="checkbox" <?= $train ?> /></td>
       <td><input value='meet' name="stake[<?= $stakeholder ?>][meet]" type ="checkbox" <?= $meet ?> /></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

they should end up like:

```
$_POST[] = array(
    'stakeholder1' => array(
        'partner'=> 'partner',
        'agreement'=> 'agreement',
        'train'=> 'train',
        'meet'=> 'meet'
    ),
    'stakeholder2' => array(
        'partner'=> 'partner',
        'agreement'=> 'agreement',
        'train'=> 'train',
        'meet'=> 'meet'
    ),
);
```

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/102528100285286815171/albums/5708634782606194689/5708634785261526130

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked just as you described. Now I just need to figure out how to split it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a different `name` tag to every `checkbox` element (you need to add `name="WhatEverYouwant"`)

and you will be able to get it by:

```
$_POST['ID Of the Element']
```

Example:

```
'<td><input type ="checkbox" name="new" checked ="checked" /></td>' : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
```

and get it by:

```
$_POST['new']
```

Comment: It is not the `id` that is picked up by `$_POST`, but `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have that in a `<form>` already, you need to give each input an id. Then in the resulting PHP script, use `$_POST['whatever_the_name_is']` (you could also use `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` depending on your form action).

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
<input type ="checkbox" ...
```

*To:*

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[]" ...
```

*Or:*

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[KEYNAME]" ...
```

**Access in PHP:**

```
foreach($_POST['stakeholderarray'] as $this_stakeholderarray){
 ...
}
```

*Or:*

```
$_POST['stakeholderarray']['KEYNAME'];
```

This works because `[]`/`[KEYNAME]` added to the end of the `name` attribute is seen as an `array` item in PHP, and can therefore be looped through. You can nest arrays this way as well, so if you want to have multiple stake holders on a single form, do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[0][0]" ... <!-- Holder 0, item 0 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[0][1]" ... <!-- Holder 0, item 1 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[1][0]" ... <!-- Holder 1, item 0 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="stakeholderarray[1][1]" ... <!-- Holder 1, item 1 -->
```

Comment: The problem here is that you won't know which elements in the `$_POST[stakeholderarray][]` array belong to which row of checkboxes. Only the ones that are checked are stored in the array.

Comment: Changed the answer a bit--wasn't thinking that he had each one assigned a specific value, rather than a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but yeowch... reduce some of the duplicate HTML in your logic:

```
print ($currentEntry['Partner'])     ? '<td><input type ="checkbox" checked ="checked" /></td>' : '<td><input type ="checkbox"  /></td>';
```

should be

```
<td><input type ="checkbox"<?php ($currentEntry['Partner'] ? ' checked ="checked"' : '' ?> /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($stakholderArray as $currentEntry) {
  print "<tr class='$bgcolor'>";
  print "<td class='left'>$currentEntry[org]</td>";
  if($currentEntry['dataFound']) {  //if data was found for current stakeholder, display it
    print '<td><input type ="checkbox" name="chkPartner['.$i.']" '.(($currentEntry['Partner'])?'checked ="checked"':'').' /></td>';
  //print the rest like this
  $i++;
}
```

You can then access them from `$_POST` like so

```
if(isset($_POST[chkPartner][$yourIndex]))
{}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actualy `id` shouldn't work. As Joseph said, form elements are sent with their names as keys. So the proper tag should be:

`<input type="checkbox" name="some_name" ... />`

When you send the form, you can get the data like `$_POST['some_name']`

If you like you can put them in an array `name="somearr[someotherarr[some_name]]]"` then the content will be available in `$_POST['somearr']['someotherar']['some_name']`

Hope that helps.

Comment: `somearr[someotherarr[some_name]]]` doesn't accomplish what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. Single level arrays work though `array[key]`.

Comment: Multi-levels work as well. Use, `somearr['someotherarr']['some_name']` instead, and that will achieve what you initially expected. :)