# How to have array of fields with names?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form like this :

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="employee[][name]"/>
  <input type="text" name="employee[][name]"/>
</form>
```

And I use the result in a php file like this :

```
echo $_POST['employee'][0]['name'];
echo $_POST['employee'][1]['name'];
```

The fields are converted in arrays. It's a dynamic form, I can add or remove some fields so it is usefull to not have a fixed name for each fields.

I want to do the same thing in Javascript/JQuery. Is tried to do `$('[name="employee[0][name]")` and it return an empty array.

I don't know what to do. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Try using javascript objects

Comment: $('[name="employee[0][name]") s/b $("[name="+employee[0][name]+"]"), anyway, you need to use objects to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name^="employee[name]"]').each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="employee[name][]" value="value1"/>
  <input type="text" name="employee[name][]" value="value2"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```