# How Get value of textarea from a HTML Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, session

I am trying to get the value of the array of a html form shown below and display using php. But my code seems to have an issue.

Please assist.

**html array**

```
<textarea   rows="1"  maxlenth = "20" class="round"    id="quantityid[]" name="quantityname[]"><?php echo $itemsale["quantity"]; ?></textarea>
<td align="center"><?php echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="add_sales.php?saveep='.$itemsale["productname"].'&return_url='.'add_sales.php'.'"><img src="images/saveicon.png" width="30" height="30" /></a></span>'; ?></td>

<textarea   rows="1"  maxlenth = "20" class="round"    id="quantityid[]" name="quantityname[]"><?php echo $itemsale["quantity"]; ?></textarea>
<td align="center"><?php echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="add_sales.php?saveep='.$itemsale["productname"].'&return_url='.'add_sales.php'.'"><img src="images/saveicon.png" width="30" height="30" /></a></span>'; ?></td>

<textarea   rows="1"  maxlenth = "20" class="round"    id="quantityid[]" name="quantityname[]"><?php echo $itemsale["quantity"]; ?></textarea>
<td align="center"><?php echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="add_sales.php?saveep='.$itemsale["productname"].'&return_url='.'add_sales.php'.'"><img src="images/saveicon.png" width="30" height="30" /></a></span>'; ?></td>
```

**my php code**

```
if(isset($_GET["saveep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["cart_sales"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["saveep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url

    foreach( $_POST['quantityname'] as $v ) {
     echo $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: And is the issue *"headers already sent"* ?

Comment: no doesn't do anything just reloads

Comment: And what are you expecting, does the form have a `action` attribute, or do you think that `header` call will actually redirect after you've echoed output ?

Comment: yes the form has the action @adeneo

Comment: And the method is set to `POST`

Answer (score 0):

Each element inside the form must have an unique `name` attribute.

Unless you treat your data to client-side to send an array, you won't be able to retrieve an array with `$_POST['quantityname']`.

Most likely only one field will be sent.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript) for a nice solution to your problem.

Comment: the form auto generates itself i need help getting the values from the array

Comment: Please do a `var_dump` on your `$_POST` variable and post it here, we need to check how your data is being formatted

Comment: var_dump gives a null @caulitomaz

Comment: Then your form / ajax request is not sending your data correctly. Please add more of your HTML (up to the form tag, submit button) and/or correspondent javascript (any $.ajax, if existent)

Comment: Also, are you sure you are sending mixed GET and POST parameters at the same time? It is technically feasible, but sort of weird/confusing to do this.