# How to post array[][] in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, multidimensional-array

in codeigniter I have to post an two-dimensional array `array[$index][$index]` to some variable.

How do I post the value from the array on `$val[$index][$index];`?

I have to try with some code like this, but didnt work corectly :

```
$val[$x][$y] = $this->input->post('criteria'[$i][$j]);
```

Any thoughts on how I should try to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: $val = $this->input->post('criteria'); ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an html Form you can add a field with name having double square brackets. Like:

```
<input name="myVal[][]" />
```

Then post this into a form to php.
In you php file write:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);'</pre>';
```

You will see posted fields there. You can get this posted data in codeigniter using:

```
 $this->input->post('myVal');
```