# PHP get post data from inputs with arrays []

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am creating a form that users can add extra fields to dynamically and every time a new input is created, it is named accountemails[type] with the type being different for each group.

I want to post this form and retrieve the data grouped by the type

For example, if I have 2 groups - group1 and group2 my inputs would be named:

```
name="accountemails[group1]"
name="accountemails[group2]"
```

And there could be multiple with the same group name

For the post in php, I tried

```
foreach($_POST["accountemails"] as $type => $email) {

}
```

Which I though would work and I could use `$type` as each group and then `$email` for each value but that only shows the last posted input value per group

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST["accountemails"])` tell you? ^^

Comment: What exactly are you doing inside the `foreach` loop? And what values does `$_POST["accountemails"]` contain (see the comment above)?

Comment: You have to discriminate the fields per array in HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9073690/498457

Comment: so i have posted g1, g2 and o1 and the var dump shows `array(4) { ["general"]=> string(2) "g2" ["orders"]=> string(2) "o1" ["renewals"]=> string(0) "" ["accounts"]=> string(0) "" } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on **Benoti's** answer, it sounds like your overwriting your `$_POST['accountemails']` data when a new value is added. Add the `group` data to an array.

```
$_POST['accountemails']['group1'] [] = "Group 1 - 1"; //Emulates html form: name = accountemails[group1][] with value of: Group 1 - 1
$_POST['accountemails']['group1'] [] = "Group 1 - 2"; //Emulates html form: name = accountemails[group1][] with value of: Group 1 - 2

$_POST['accountemails']['group2'] [] = "Group 2 - 1"; //Emulates html form: name = accountemails[group2][] with value of: Group 2 - 1
$_POST['accountemails']['group2'] [] = "Group 2 - 2"; //Emulates html form: name = accountemails[group2][] with value of: Group 2 - 2

foreach ($_POST as $v) {

    foreach ($v['group1'] as $email) {

        echo "Group 1 Email: " . $email;
        echo "<br>";
    }

    foreach ($v['group2'] as $email) {

        echo "Group 2 Email: " . $email;
        echo "<br>";     
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Group 1 Email: Group 1 - 1
Group 1 Email: Group 1 - 2
Group 2 Email: Group 2 - 1
Group 2 Email: Group 2 - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple form input with the same name, you need to add double brackets at the very last end of the name.

```
 name="accountemails[group1][]"
 name="accountemails[group2][]"
```

Then if the user adds extra-fields for group1, each new accountemails in each different group will be added to an array that you'll be able to retrieve in your foreach loop.

Comment: The indexes (`group1`/`group2`) are different, so using `name="accountemails[group1]"`/`name="accountemails[group2]"` (without the extra brackets) is valid and will submit both fields into the `$_POST['accountemails']` array. You're essentially making it another dimention wide when adding `[]` at the end, which isn't needed.

Comment: @Qirel but OP has stated that there could be multiple records with the same group name e.g. [group1]. So I'm guessing that OP is attempting to add data to the array of `accountemails[group1]` or `accountemails[group2]` which means this answer above would be correct as all OP is doing at the moment is overwriting `['group1']` or `['group2']` when a new value has been added.

Comment: @Qirel Just to clarify, I'm not trying cause a war :-) I'm just curious because this would of been my logic for resolving. Obviously if I'm wrong then put me straight.

Comment: this is what my form looks like: https://s27.postimg.org/fk54dsm6r/Screen_Shot_2016_12_11_at_14_45_59.png - so each input would be accountemails[general][] and accountemails[orders][]

Comment: P.S. I have added [] to the end of the input names

Comment: @Kitson88 Who said anything about a war? ;-) We're all friendly here! You might very well be right, though - I think I might've miss-interpreted the problem (and missed entirely the "*And there could be multiple with the same group name*" part of OPs question!).

Comment: @Qirel *We're all friendly here!* - I wish that was the case :-P Cheers for getting back to me.

Comment: Yes we're all here to help :-) I only give the answer as how I understand the problem and how I did it many time in this case.

Comment: Did you see my screenshot? How do I handle the POST data in PHP?

Comment: @charlie See comments above and Benoti's answer. Add `[]` to the end of your form array to add elements to your `$_POST` array. At the moment, it sounds like your overwriting your data as the values are not being added to a sub-array.

Comment: Yes i saw your screenshots, the foreach loop need to be different. I didn't correct it. Try to loop in each group, -> foreach($accountdetails['group1'] as $email)

Comment: @Benoti what is `$accountdetails` ?

Comment: i have tried this `foreach($_POST["accountemails"] as $type)` and then inside here - `foreach($type as $t)`