# JQuery: Combine sets of field names and values into an object and then push into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form with three sets of fields.

Like this:

```html
 <form>
    <div class="food">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <textarea name="" value=""></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="drinks">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <textarea name="" value=""></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="gifts">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="" value="" />
        <textarea name="" value=""></textarea>
    </div>
    </form>
```

How do I combine field names and values in each div into their own json object, push the objects into an array, and then add the array to a hidden input field before submission?

Comment: `</teaxtarea>` is not valid HTML tag.

Comment: fixed typo. thanks

Comment: Your fields have neither name nor value

Comment: Could you explain some logic behind why you would want to do that ? I don't know why you would do all that and want to add it to a hidden field, because you can do all that on server side.
And specify also which language you'd like to use (apparently jquery, but that's one client side)

Comment: I want to keep the fields grouped together before sending them to the database. Maybe I'm complicating this but I just need to keep the data together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript

Comment: @JsusSalv Well you can do that on server side also. It will be easier and more efficient. What language are you using on server side ?

Comment: That would be great. No preference either way. Either JQuery or PHP is fine.

Comment: Check the link that Alexandru-IonutMihai posted, it should answer your question. If you need help, I could give you a working code example. (and please mention me in the comments with '@', otherwise I don't see you've answered me :-D )

Comment: thank you. I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to create array and inside you can return object for each `div`.

```js
var data = $('form > div').map(function() {
  var obj = {}
  $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function() {
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
  })
  return obj;
}).get()

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="food">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="11" />
    <textarea name="c" value="111"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="drinks">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="22" />
    <textarea name="c" value="222"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="gifts">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="33" />
    <textarea name="c" value="333"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that proper way is to get values is by `val` and textarea doesn't use value property instead https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1805/

Comment: ok. so check for field type and get .text() if it's textarea.

Comment: No just use `val()` but insert value like this `<textarea name="c">111</textarea>` and when you change value on front-end it will get new value as you can see in jsfiddle