# Parse arrays sent with form

Tags: django, http

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073794). In short, it transforms:

```
<input type="text" name="object[0][color]" value="red">
<input type="text" name="object[0][doors]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="object[0][color]" value="green">
<input type="text" name="object[0][doors]" value="4>
```

Into a PHP associative array:

```
'object' => array(
    '0'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'doors'=>'2'
    ),
    '1'=>array(
        'color'=>'green',
        'doors'=>'4'
    )
)
```

In Django, I try to do the same, but when I print request.POST, I get:

```
<QueryDict: {'object[0][color]': ['red'], 'object[0][doors]': ['2'], 'object[1][color]': ['green'], 'object[1][doors]': ['4']}>
```

How to convert it to a proper dict?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

`myDict = dict(queryDict.iterlists())`