# html dynamic name with php

Tags: javascript, php

I try to make dynamic add/remove table with jquery. The problem of how I can pass value from the table to PHP because the HTML name dynamically generated by jquery. I know it can solve by making php loop but I don't know what kind of loop.
Sorry for my messy code cause I'm still new in this kind.

[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLRxd.png)

```
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-md-10 table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
           <thead>
              <tr >
                 <th class="text-center">
                    Ticket Type
                 </th>
                 <th class="text-center">
                    Price(RM)
                 </th>
                 <th class="text-center">
                    Quantity
                 </th>
                 <th class="text-center">
                    Setting
                 </th>
                 <!-- <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;"> -->
                 <!-- </th> -->
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr id="paid0" data-id="0" class="hidden">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <td data-name="paid_ticket_name">
                       <input type="text" name="paid_ticket_name0"  placeholder="e.g General Admission, VIP, etc" class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <td data-name="paid_ticket_price">
                          <input type="number" name="paid_ticket_price0" class="form-control"/>
                       </td>
                       <td data-name="paid_ticket_quantity">
                          <input name="paid_ticket_quantity0" placeholder="100" class="form-control"/>
                       </td>
                    </div>
                    <td data-name="paid_del">
                       <button name="paid-del0" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove"></button>
                    </td>
                 </div>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic1">
           <tbody>
              <tr id="free0" data-id="0" class="hidden">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <td data-name="free_ticket_name">
                       <input type="text" name="free_ticket_name0"  placeholder="e.g General Admission, VIP, etc" class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <td data-name="free_ticket_price">
                          <input type="text" value="FREE" placeholder="FREE" name="free_ticket_price0" disabled="" class="form-control"/>
                       </td>
                       <td data-name="free_ticket_quantity">
                          <input name="free_ticket_quantity0" placeholder="100" class="form-control"/>
                       </td>
                    </div>
                    <td data-name="paid_del">
                       <button name="paid-del0" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove"></button>
                    </td>
                 </div>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-12 btn-toolbar">
           <a id="add_row_paid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Paid Ticket</a>
           <a id="add_row_free" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Free Ticket</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add_row_paid").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "paid"+newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
        $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });

            var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
            c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
            c.appendTo($(td));
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add delete button and td
    /*
    $("<td></td>").append(
        $("<button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>")
            .click(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            })
    ).appendTo($(tr));
    */

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
       $(this).closest("tr").remove();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hidden form element to the page, such as

```
<input type="hidden" name="row_count" value="0">
```

and each time the button add_row_paid is clicked (in your Javascript code above) you could update the value of this hidden input field:

```
$("input[name='row_count']").val(newid);
```

So when the form is submitted, in addition to each of the rows in the table, you will also have a field containing the ID of the latest row in the table. This can then be used to loop over each ID (row) in the table, for example:

```
foreach (range(0, $_POST['row_count']) as $id) {
    // code to run for each row here, accessing cells using format such as $_POST["paid_ticket_quantity$id"]
}
```

Alternativey, you could restructure your form elements to be in an array form, such as in the answer at [POST an array from an HTML form without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript#9073794) - this way you would be able to loop through each row of the table without the need of an additional counter field to store the number of rows.