# How do I get a HTML div element to loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block of code, a quiz creation template, and i need the block of code for the question and possible answers to be looped, for however many times the user asks for. I have been trying for hours and im really not sure whats wrong.

```
<div id="questionform" class="modal">
```

I already have the amount of questions the user would like under this line of code.

```
var amount = prompt("Please enter the amount of questions you would like", "<amount goes here>");
```

below is the javascript i am using to try and loop the writing within the div.

```
var i;
var amount;
var contents = document.getElementById("questionform").innerHTML;
for (i = 1; i=amount; i++) {
a.document.write(contents);
}
```

Comment: Your bottom snippet does not define a value for `amount`.  Also your `for` statement is malformed.  You set the value of `i` to 1, and then set the value of `i` to what is in `amount`, which is undefined, and then you try to increment that undefined

Comment: The second part of the `for()` loop header should be a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: What is `a.document`? You're writing the same contents every time.

Comment: also, never, ever, use `document.write`. It [does not do what you think it does](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript), use normal modern JS APIs instead, in this case `.textContent = ...`

Comment: You should have an array of questions, and loop over that, putting the questions into the DIV by appending to `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar `textContent`, not `innerHTML`. You only use the latter if you actually need to create HTML out of string data, in which case you should pause and ask yourself if you can't do that safely, instead, using normal DOM API functions instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans He probably would want to structure the questions in some way, probably using nested divs and spans.

Comment: And learn how JS works, because none of this code makes sense, and gets the absolute basics of not just JS, but even just programming a for loop, wrong. I strongly recommend finding a modern HTML5 + JS (ES6+, not ES5 or earlier) tutorial, or a good book on learning JS from 2019 or newer.

Comment: i reallly am not sure what i am doing with javascript. i am very new to it and this for loop was just what i saw off a website.

Comment: If you are looking for a good resource to pick up JavaScript you can't go wrong with [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) It's an open source book that's freely available and absolutely fantastic.

Comment: We are helping by pointing out logic flaws.  Also your question states you already have the number of questions from a prompt, but your bottom snippet doesn't show that.  So that is a disconnect between what you say you have, and what you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in your for-loop is wrong. You have an assignment instead of an evaluation.

> for (i = 1; i=amount; i++)

You should be creating elements and appending them to the DOM. Avoid using `document.write`. Also, please begin indexing at zero, unless you *need* to start at 1.

#### Update

If you provide a name attribute to your input fields, they will be submitted with the form on submit.

```js
input.setAttribute('name', 'answer[]');
```

When you hit submit, the input field values will be sent to the server as:

```js
answer=foo&answer=bar
```

or:

```js
{ "answer" : [ "foo", "bar" ] }
```

Refer to this if you are still confused: [POST an array from an HTML form without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript)

### Example

```js
let amount = prompt("Please enter the amount of questions you would like", 5);
let questionForm = document.getElementById("question-form");
let answerList = questionForm.querySelector(".answer-list");

for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  let inputWrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
  let label = document.createElement('LABEL');
  let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('name', 'answer[]');
  label.textContent = 'Answer ' + String.fromCharCode(i + 65) + ': ';
  inputWrapper.classList.add('input-wrapper');
  inputWrapper.appendChild(label);
  inputWrapper.appendChild(input);
  answerList.appendChild(inputWrapper);
}
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.input-wrapper label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form id="question-form" class="modal">
  <div class="answer-list"></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, but how would i then use the answer boxes created to put into sql? how would i give them variable names?

Comment: @katekatekate The SQL is up to you. I did edit my response to include a form submission example.