# How To Add Data Into Array By Input Html Dynamically in php

Tags: php, html

My question is, How to add data into array by HTML input and not only one value but add as much as I want

```
<body>
    <form action="oop.php" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="no[]">
        <input type="number" name='no[]">
        <input type="number" name="no[]">
        <input type="submit" name="sub">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $no= $_POST['no'];
    $ex = explode(",", $no);
    $item = array ();
    foreach ($ex as $item) {
        echo $item; // Do something with item
        print_r($item);
    }
}
?>
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it correctly. you just need to print the item valus outside the foreach loop. Inside the loop it will always print the last value

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
  $no= $_POST['no'];
 // $ex = explode(",", $no);
  $items = array ();
  foreach ($no as $item) {
      echo $item; // Do something with item
       $items[] = $item;
   }
   print_r($items);

}
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help :) an upvote as well please

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $no= $_POST['no'];
    $nos = explode(",", $no);
    $items = array (); // careful here you are using $item twice !
    foreach ($nos as $no) {
        $items[] = $no;
    }
    var_dump($items);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this pattern `no[]` then you are sending an array so there is no need to use explode.

also the line `$item = array ();` doing nothing becouse you are filling  `$item` in the foreach.

So, change your code as follow:

```
<body>
<form action="array_check.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="no[]">
    <input type="number" name="no[]">
    <input type="number" name="no[]">
    <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $no = $_POST['no'];
    foreach ($no as $item) {
        echo $item ; // Do something with item
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```